# Does jQuery DataTables fetches all data from the database in a single request or using pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

Someone Please help me 
    I am using bootstrap datatable. I want to know that datatable fetch all data from mysql on a single request or uses pagination to fetch the data.

Answer (score 2):

From [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Processing-modes):

> DataTables has two different modes of processing data (ordering, searching, etc. of data):
>
> - Client-side processing - the full data set is loaded up-front and data processing is done in the browser.
> - Server-side processing - an Ajax request is made for every table redraw, with only the data required for each display returned. The data processing is performed on the server.

You can use either one depending on the amount of the data and your project needs.